# Problem with \usepackage[margin]{geometry} and \usepackage{todonotes}

Tags: margins, article, marginnote

I have problem with `\usepackage[margin]{geometry}` and `\usepackage{todonotes}`.

The todo notes intrusion on margin. I want in my article using more wider margin.

[image: problem image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand\Right{\textcolor{red}{(Right) Lorem ipsum  dolor sit amet}}
\newcommand\Left{\textcolor{cyan}{(Left) Lorem ipsum  dolor sit amet}}


\begin{document}
\section*{Two \texttt{marginpar} in the same paragraph} 

Lorem \reversemarginpar\marginpar{\Left}
ipsum  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\normalmarginpar\marginpar{\Right} Ut purus elit\ldots
\vspace{2cm} \todo{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome toTeX SX! Well… declare a wider margin, e.g. `margin=1in`  or simply `hmargin=1in`.

Comment: Also please make your example compilable. Where is `\Left` and `\Right` defined?

Comment: @daleif, thanks I forgot define \Left and \Right

Comment: @Bernard thanks, Now, I understand difference about 0.75in and 1.

Comment: You can set `marginparwidth` as an option to `geometry`. As far as I can see from the `geometry` code `marginparwidth` is not automatically adjusted to fit within the given margins.